# How to call function when range slider changes

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I need to call function when user changes range slider and also I need to send value to that function... I am using vue js. I have given code below. I need to call that function whenever user changes the slider.

```
                  <div
                    class="title title--danger "
                    :style="{color: this.$themes.danger}"
                  >Set Value</div>
                  <va-slider
                    color="danger"
                    value-visible
                    v-model="value"
                  />


                 //below is my function 
              data(){
                return{
              value: '' 
                }
              },
              watch: {
                value(newVal, oldVal){
                  alert('value = ' + newVal);
                }
              }
```

Comment: Please provide more information to be able to help you

Comment: Could you reformat your code in your question? It's quite hard to read and seems to be an incomplete reproducible example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your template, the value is already being bound to a property on your Vue instance (`value`) via the `v-model` attribute on `<va-slider>`. You can leverage this and a watcher that is triggered whenever that value changes:

```
{
  data() {
    return { value: '' };
  },
  watch: {
    value(newVal, oldVal){
      alert('value = ' + newVal);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: its not working  bro..

Comment: @pavankp can you paste all your code into your question?

Comment: i have updated with your code bro...please check it out

Comment: We're gonna need the _whole lot_, not just the snippet above

Comment: ya bro now its wrkng ...thank you